# Unable to connect to redis with ip address

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I installed redis on my server. I am unable to connect to server with ip address but able to connect with `localhost`. I am unable to connect to this redis from other servers too. What could be the reason?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-211:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.70.211  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.95.255
        inet6 fe80::1052:1ff:fee4:cfdd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:52:01:e4:cf:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 974  bytes 304521 (304.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 937  bytes 130927 (130.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 794  bytes 63335 (63.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 794  bytes 63335 (63.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-211:~$ redis-cli -h 172.31.70.211
Could not connect to Redis at 172.31.70.211:6379: Connection refused
not connected> 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-211:~$ redis-cli -h localhost
localhost:6379> 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-211:~$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:6379> 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-211:~$
```

I am able to connect to this process with ip address when it is different application

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-70-211:~$ python3 -m http.server 6379 &
[1] 992
ubuntu@ip-172-31-70-211:~$ Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 6379 (http://0.0.0.0:6379/) ...

ubuntu@ip-172-31-70-211:~$ curl 172.31.91.211:6379
172.31.91.211 - - [27/Mar/2023 07:01:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".bash_history">.bash_history</a></li>
<li><a href=".bash_logout">.bash_logout</a></li>
<li><a href=".bashrc">.bashrc</a></li>
<li><a href=".cache/">.cache/</a></li>
<li><a href=".profile">.profile</a></li>
<li><a href=".rediscli_history">.rediscli_history</a></li>
<li><a href=".ssh/">.ssh/</a></li>
<li><a href=".sudo_as_admin_successful">.sudo_as_admin_successful</a></li>
<li><a href=".viminfo">.viminfo</a></li>
<li><a href="Development/">Development/</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change bind IP

1. Go to the redis file location and open the Redis configuration file with a text editor

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
   ```
2. change bind IP (you can use allowed need IP also)

   ```bash
   bind 0.0.0.0 ::
   ```
3. finally restart the redis

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart redis
   ```